# Arrange dynamic content horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page where dynamic content arranges vertically one below the other.

Content is **small boxes** & I want to **arrange them horizontally** next to each other.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Mabye http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/ might help?

Comment: It would help if you show us an example of the (generated) HTML and/or the JS/PHP script that generates the content, along with the CSS you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**   `display:inline;`

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution as Babiker Suggest.

```
<style type="text/css">
div.inline { float:left; }
.clearBoth { clear:both; }
</style>
<div class="inline">box1 </div>
<div class="inline">box2 </div>
<div class="inline">box3 </div>
```